# Have a fallback for ImportValue on a CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I've got two projects (backoffice and frontoffice) deployed using CloudFormation.

In the frontoffice, I import some DynamoDB table names from the backoffice stack as Environment variables for my Lambdas.

To run some acceptance tests I need to sometimes deploy the frontoffice withtout deploying the backoffice. Therefore, the frontoffice will try to do an ImportValue of an Export that doesn't exists.

Is there any pattern that would allow me to get the Frontend deployed anyway - and then handle the lack of value in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an additional `Parameter` to `frontoffice` indicating whether you are going to deploy with `backoffice` or not.

Based on the value of the parameter, you could use [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) and/or [Fn::If](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) to either import or not the DynamoDB table names.

For a fully automated solution without any extra Parameter, you would have to use [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). The resource would be a lambda function, which would use AWS SDK to query CloudFormation stacks and check for `backoffice`.